# Split view in Custom LWC page

Tags: slds

I have custom LWC page(it's a site page) Which I'm implementing the Global Header and Split View.

**Global Header Code**

```
    <header class="slds-global-header_container branding-header slds-no-print oneHeader" id="oneHeader"
            data-aura-rendered-by="378:80;a" data-aura-class="oneHeader">
            <div data-aura-rendered-by="385:80;a" class="oneSystemMessage" data-aura-class="oneSystemMessage">
            </div>
            <div class="slds-global-header slds-grid slds-grid--align-spread" style="height: 97px">
                <div class="slds-global-header__item" data-aura-rendered-by="391:80;a">

                    <img src={Banner} alt="banner Image"
                        style="-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;border:none;max-width:100%;outline:none;width: 100px;vertical-align: bottom;"
                        width="32" />
                </div>
                <div class="slds-text-heading_small slds-p-right_small"> Welcome <b>{name}</b> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="bBottom">

            </div>
        </header>
```

When I add the Split view in My code, initial content hided  below the global header.

```
<div class="demo-only" style="display:flex;width:16rem;height:37.5rem">
                    <div class="slds-split-view_container slds-is-open">
                        <button
                            class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon slds-split-view__toggle-button slds-is-open"
                            aria-controls="split-view-id" aria-expanded="true" title="Close Split View">
                            <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_x-small" aria-hidden="true">
                                <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#left"></use>
                            </svg>
                            <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close Split View</span>
                        </button>
                        <article aria-hidden="false" id="split-view-id"
                            class="slds-split-view slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-grow">

                            <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
                                <div class="slds-split-view__list-header slds-grid">
                                    <span>Time Sheet
                                        <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small slds-icon-text-default slds-align-top"
                                            aria-hidden="true">
                                            <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#arrowdown">
                                            </use>
                                        </svg>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                                <ul aria-describedby="entity-header">
                                    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item slds-is-active">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
                                            onclick={handleSelect} aria-current="true" name="One">01/06/2020 to
                                            1/19/2020</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item ">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
                                            onclick={handleSelect} aria-current="true" name="two">01/06/2020 to
                                            1/19/2020</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item  ">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
                                            onclick={handleSelect} aria-current="true" name="three">01/06/2020 to
                                            1/19/2020</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slds-nav-vertical__item ">
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-nav-vertical__action"
                                            onclick={handleSelect} aria-current="true" name="four">01/06/2020 to
                                            1/19/2020</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your code structure, but considering you are putting the first snippet (`<header>`... ) inside the first div of second snippet, you can change the line:

```
<div class="slds-split-view_container slds-is-open">
```

to

```
<div class="slds-split-view_container slds-is-open" style="position:relative;z-index:199;">
```